# Pinch Gesture not working with imageVIew

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am trying to zoom in and out an imageView

here is the code

```
- (void)pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
   if (handSelected == YES)
   {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        NSLog(@"gesture.scale = %f", gesture.scale);

        CGFloat currentScale = self.imgHand.frame.size.width / self.imgHand.bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat newScale = currentScale * gesture.scale;

        if (newScale < 1.0) {
            newScale = 1.0;
        }
        if (newScale > 4.0) {
            newScale = 4.0;
        }

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(newScale, newScale);
        self.imgHand.transform = transform;
        gesture.scale = 1;
    }
   }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self adjustRingPressed:self];
    self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    self.imgHand.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *gst = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.imgHand action:@selector(pinch:)];
    [gst setDelegate:self];
    [self.imgHand addGestureRecognizer:gst];

}
```

it seems that my pinch Code never runs

Comment: Try setting target to self and adding the gesture recognizer to self.view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add:

```
self.imgHand.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
```

by default UIImageView has userInteractionEnabled = FALSE

Answer (score 0):

make it a function of `gesture`like template code below:

```
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```