# How to add an Image array in to UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

i am newbie in iOS Development i make an Application that contain ScrollView and i add an array images inside scrollview but it is not working.

I write a code for that

```
for(int index=0; index < [self.imagesa count]; index++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *image=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
    UIImageView *bigImage=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    bigImage.bounds=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.height);
    bigImage.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.height);
    [bigImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    [self.objectarray insertObject:bigImage atIndex:index];
    CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width*[self.objectarray count], self.zoomScroll.frame.size.height);
    [self.zoomScroll setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
    [self.zoomScroll addSubview:bigImage];
    [self.zoomScroll addSubview:[self.objectarray objectAtIndex:index]];
}
```

it is add my all images in one imageview. not a one by one in Scrollview please give me solution for that

Here object array is NSMutableArray array and imagesa is also NSMutableArray and it is contain image URLlink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the X co-ordinate of your "bigImage.frame". Your adding images on same co-ordinates, one over the other. It should be...

```
bigImage.frame=CGRectMake(index * self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width, 0, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: thnx bro but i want a space between images how it possible?

Comment: #RoHaN also i add a UIPanGestureRecognizer and UIPinchGestureRecognizer to my bigimage then it is not working.

Comment: For space just add some overhead to x co-ordinate. Something like 10.0f. "bigImage.frame=CGRectMake(index * self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width + 10.0f, 0, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.height);"

Comment: Can you show me the code for gesture recognizer, what have u tried.

Comment: now i want to zoom UISCrollView when button is pressed How it is Possible?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content).

Comment: Bro when i add a pinch gesture then image was pinched outside of Scrollview how i add pinch only inside of scrollview size?

Comment: add pinch gesture to your image view, [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616210/pinch-gesture-not-working-with-imageview)